# Dismissed dialog shows up again after screen unlock

Tags: android, dialog

i observed already a few times that an already dismissed dialog shows up again after the phone is a while locked and then gets unlocked. this happens once in a while, not always.

the code that i use is pretty straight forward:

```
showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, PhotoList>(){
    @Override
    protected PhotoList doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // load and return data
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(PhotoList result) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
        // display data
    }
}.execute();
....
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog");
    switch(id){
    case DIALOG_LOADING:
        return ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    default:
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
}
```

now, what happens is: the dialog shows, data gets loaded and the dialog gets dismissed. so far so good, just that the dialog shows up again after the phone was locked for a while and i unlock it again.

any ideas why that could happen?

thanks
simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not say it with 100% certainty, but I think this was somehow related to debugging. It never happes to me with apps that were compiled for production.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you put the `showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);` in `onResume()` callback. That's the most probable reason that the dialog show up as `onResume()` will be invoked after screen unlock.

Comment: Then I cannot be sure what will be called after screen unlock as some manufacturer may change the behavior. You may try adding debug code in before the `showDialog()` to see if it is being called after screen unlock.